# How to make Microsoft Store app to access internet on proxy

Tags: proxy, updates

I have a problem with Microsoft Store updates for the apps. I can't install the updates for the apps in the store. I think because of proxy. If I connect the notebook to a public network and turn off Proxy, the updates will run without errors. Therefore I have activated the following Proxy URLs on the Proxy:

- login.live.com
- login.windows.net
- account.live.com
- clientconfig.passport.net
- windowsphone.com
- *.wns.windows.com
- *.microsoft.com
- *.s-microsoft.com
- www.msftncsi.com (prior to Windows 10, version 1607)
- www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt (replaces www.msftncsi.com starting with Windows 10, version 1607)

Unfortunately without success.
I already reset Store and tried a lot and maybe you have a solution for my proxy.

Do you have an idea?